# Odd behavior on including iostream header-- odd compiler generated function based on first symbol?

Tags: c++, stl, g++, iostream, clang++

I noticed some [odd behavior](https://godbolt.org/z/bnM5d3) when including the `iostream` header in GCC.

Edit: Odd behavior code, since a comment wanted it direclty instead of a view of the code with the dissasembly:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
int main() {}
```

Really, any simple `#include <iostream>` will do with some other symbols in the file, similarly odd assembly will be generated.
(Edit end).

I understand that it needs to setup some global static variables, so I understand the need for `__static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int)` which within calls some functions of `std::ios_base`.

However, this function itself is always called oddly-- the compiler creates a label / function based on the first symbol encountered in the file. If no such symbol exists, it uses the filename (which is what I would have expected, and what clang always does).

However, even then, the whole thing is a bit bizarre, all this helper does is set up registers with constants before calling the above function. On GCC, inside the `__static_initialization...` function, the constant-set-up registers are compared with constants before proceeding, on clang, no registers are set up at all, no registers are compared either.

Why was this done (by which I mean, the design decision, if anyone can fathom a guess, not the literal code that causes it, but the code too would be interesting).

Comment: Include the "odd behavior" code in your question, not as a link to an external site.

Comment: It constructs `ios_base`, I don't see what's confusing about that?  There is a global object and it must be constructed  the `__static_init...` function is where that happens.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm the link was to Matthew Godbolt's compiler explorer, which I've *often* seen used to link to when asking questions about oddly generated assembly

Comment: @Tumbleweed53 constructing ios_base is the obvious part, what's weird is *why* is it called via *another* generated label based on the first symbol within the file, and *why* does it set up two registers with constants, only to compare them yet again with the same constants, in GCC (but not clang)

Comment: Links like that can be used to provide supplementary information, but the essential parts you're asking about should be included in the question. That prevents about the links breaking (or being inaccessible to someone reading your question), and allow someone else searching to find the code in your question.

Comment: While I understand your reasoning, I can quickly find many posts that do not do this without moderator intervention by means of a simple google search, in fact on a meta-post it was mentioned that godbolt links are generally considered as though they don't expire. That said, I've added the two lines of code referenced.